# Some applications start very slowly

Tags: wayland, 23.10

I was having problems with slowly launching programs in my Manjaro installation and decided to try out Ubuntu 23.10 for a change. But looks like I have the same problems here. Any ideas why this might be? At least Brave browser, Edge browser and Obsidian are currently some of the ones that are slow. I'm using Gnome Wayland.

First I installed Brave from the snaps and it started up quickly but I couldn't enable the Wayland ozone settings as it said that it couldn't find the Wayland display. I assumed this was because of snap sandbox or something like that so I decided to try the official release via the custom apt repository. That let me enable the Wayland ozone, but it is very slow to start. Around 20 secs or so. And this is the only error it gives me:

```
[13954:13954:1024/081010.644503:ERROR:policy_logger.cc(154)] :components/enterprise/browser/controller/chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(163) Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
[13954:13954:1024/081015.004667:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(577)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not part of the idle inhibition specification: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/idle-inhibit-spec/latest/
```